# -1: Unknown error while unlocking redmi 3s+ bootloader

Tags: bootloader-lock, redmi

So I tried to unlock bootloader of my Redmi 3s+ .It shows error " -1:Unknown error" but it also displays Unlock button .Downloaded the flash tool and rebooted the phone couple of times but nothing . Anyone please help me out Guys .
Can I click the unlock ? Wouldn't that ruin my phone ?

http://en.miui.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=1796588&aid=2914199&from=album&page=1&mobile=2